# how to make application with time limit before it automatically closed in C

Tags: c

For example, the time limit is set to 15 seconds, and then the program automatically closed after 15 seconds, how to do this in C, thanks in advance

Comment: try to use the function sleep()

Comment: @Kolyunya : Try searching on internet.

Comment: Call `alarm` with the time limit.  When the alarm goes off it will send a SIGALRM.  Handle the signal and die gracefully.  Posix systems anyway.

Comment: What operating system?  This is important to the APIs that can be used.

Comment: Even ignoring the 'related' questions on the RHS of the page, the Stack Overflow query term `[c] limit time` comes up with a selection of appropriate questions with answers.  Which of them did you look at before asking this question?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a POSIX system then use [`alarm(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm) (credit to @Duck for suggesting this first in his comment):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sighandler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGALRM)
        exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    signal(SIGALRM, sighandler);
    alarm(15);

    // do things here
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether I'd consider calling `exit()` from a signal handler "*die gracefully*".

Comment: @alk Yeah setting a *quit flag* or *quit event* (or both) in the program is way better, however it illustrates the point I think.

Comment: @Hazwan What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Hazwan I don't think Windows supports the code I have provided.  I posted a comment 5 hours ago asking what operating system you were using, as it affects the answer, and I got no reply.